# Find infimum of the sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $x_{2}>x_{1}>0$
$$L(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}(\frac{1}{n^{x_{1}}}+\frac{1}{n^{x_{2}}})$$
Where $a_{n}=\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+\frac{n}{d}}\cos(\ln(\frac{n}{d^{2}}))$

Problem:

> Find $\inf_{h\ge 0}L(N+h)$ For given natural $N$

The things i done:

$\inf_{h\ge 0}L(N+h)=L(N)+\inf_{h\ge 0}\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+h}a_{n}(\frac{1}{n^{x_{1}}}+\frac{1}{n^{x_{2}}})$

I tried to use estymation, find lower bound for $M(N,h):=\sum_{n=N+1}^{N+h}a_{n}(\frac{1}{n^{x_{1}}}+\frac{1}{n^{x_{2}}})$

I am looking for such f that $M(N,h)=\theta(f(h))$

Any ideas?

Regards.